# Se puede eliminar un proyecto que esta subido a la play store, y reemplazarlo por otro con el mismo nombre del paquete?

Tags: java, android-studio

compañeros, tengo una pequeña pregunta. Tengo una aplicación en la tienda play Store, pero debido a la nueva actualización de android studio se me vino la idea de hacer otro proyecto con el mismo nombre del paquete y la misma keyStore para ver si me acepta las actualizaciones. ¿sera posible? ¿no tendre ningun problema? o habrá que hacer otras cosas adicionales ademas del nombre del paquete?.
Ayuda porfa plisss

Answer (score 2):

No elimines la app de la tienda. Para actualizar en la tienda sólo debes generar una nueva apk firmada con una nueva versión.

Para subir la versión de la aplicación, basta con abrir `app/build.gradle.` y modificar `versionCode` y `versionName` ejemplo:

Antes:

```
versionCode 1 
versionName "1.0"
```

Después:

```
versionCode 101 
versionName "1.0.1"
```

Si no se actualiza la versión, la tienda no permitirá subir una nueva apk con una versión ya existente.

Comment: Gracias Habib, pero eso ya lo sabia, solo quiero saber si lo puedo hacer con otro proyecto nuevo.

Comment: Tu respuesta es muy util, pero no lo que pregunta ...

Comment: Si el caso es crear un nuevo proyecto en a Play Store sólo hay que cambiar el paquete. La misma Key store te funciona, aunque lo ideal es que si cambiaron los datos de la organización o ubicación, generes una nueva key.